# Can someone explain why LWP::Simple is satisfied by perl-libwww-perl?

Tags: perl, rpm

Installing Munin on RHEL 6 from RPM available at, http://pkgs.repoforge.org/  most installs were ok but when installing munin-node got this:

```
rpm -Uvh munin-node-1.2.5-1.el5.rf.noarch.rpm
warning: munin-node-1.2.5-1.el5.rf.noarch.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 6b8d79e6: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        perl(LWP::Simple) is needed by munin-node-1.2.5-1.el5.rf.noarch
```

Spent a while looking for an PRM for LWP::Simple (want to avoid CPAN to automate future installations easier). I did some yum searches. Searched some Repos. I tried a few LWP packages but eventually through googling came to this page:

http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=perl(LWP%3A%3ASimple)

This lists the package: perl-libwww-perl  on a lark I installed this package via yum. This satsified the LWP:Simple dependency. But I have no idea why... plus a little frustrated it didn't come up in earlier searches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`perl-libwww-perl` contains the entire CPAN [`libwww-perl`](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.03/) package, including `LWP/Simple.pm`. Although I'm sure how RPM dependencies work, but it seems to me that RPM [automatically adds](http://www.rpm.org/wiki/PackagerDocs/Dependencies#InterpretersandShells) `Provides: perl(LWP::Simple) = 6.00` when the RPM package is being built.

---

```
$ perl -E 'say for grep {-f} map {"$_/LWP/Simple.pm"} @INC'
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/LWP/Simple.pm

$ ./usr/lib/rpm/perl.prov "/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/LWP/Simple.pm"
perl(LWP::Simple) = 6.00
```

Comment: Thank you... at least explains why it satisfies the dependency. As I wanted to avoid CPAN in installing these modules. I am curious if/why a yum search for variations on simple and lwp did not return this package. Would be useful.

Comment: I think it is a histroical misnomer. All other perl RPMS are named perl-TopPackage or some variation thereof. LWP is the only one breaking ranks.